How can I match the fixed range of a slider to a dynamic range in SwiftUI?
I need to position one purple circle on the left and one yellow circle on the right. I want to map the slider value, which ranges from -1.0 to 1.0, to these circles so that when the slider value is 1.0, the yellow circle is at the right boundary, and when the slider value is -1.0, the purple circle is at the left boundary. I'm almost there and just need a little help. The circle's position is adjustable, and the canvas can also be dragged.
This is the simplest way I could phrase my question about mapping a slider's fixed value to a dynamic range. The test code might seem extensive, but this is the minimum I could provide to demonstrate my issue.
Code for iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let maxCanvasVisibilitySize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 400.0, height: 300.0)

    @State private var maxCanvasImaginarySize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 400.0, height: 300.0)
    
    @State private var canvasLastOffset: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var canvasCurrentOffset: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var canvasIsDragging: Bool = Bool()
    
    private let circleSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
    @State private var circleLastOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 500.0, height: .zero)
    @State private var circleCurrentOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 500.0, height: .zero)
    @State private var circleIsDragging: Bool = Bool()
    
    private let circle2Size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    @State private var circle2LastOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: -400.0, height: .zero)
    @State private var circle2CurrentOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: -400.0, height: .zero)
    @State private var circle2IsDragging: Bool = Bool()
    
    @State private var percentage: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    
    @State private var max: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var min: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            GeometryReader { geometryValue in
                
                ZStack {
                    
                    Color.black
                        .gesture(canvasDragGesture)
                    
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.yellow)
                        .frame(width: circleSize.width, height: circleSize.height)
                        .offset(circleCurrentOffset)
                        .offset(canvasCurrentOffset)
                        .gesture(circleDragGesture)
                    
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.purple)
                        .frame(width: circle2Size.width, height: circle2Size.height)
                        .offset(circle2CurrentOffset)
                        .offset(canvasCurrentOffset)
                        .gesture(circle2DragGesture)
                    
                }
                .overlay(screenRectangle(string: "VisibilitySize", size: maxCanvasVisibilitySize, cornerRadius: 0, color: .red, topOffset: false).overlay(Color.red.frame(width: 4.0).opacity(0.5)))
                .overlay(
                    screenRectangle(string: "max - min Size:", size: CGSize(width: (max - min), height: maxCanvasVisibilitySize.height), cornerRadius: 0, color: Color.green, dash: true)
                        .overlay(Color.green.frame(width: 4.0).opacity(0.5))
                        .offset(x: min + (max - min)/2.0)
                        .offset(canvasCurrentOffset)
                    
                )
                
            }
            .frame(width: maxCanvasVisibilitySize.width, height: maxCanvasVisibilitySize.height)
            
            SliderView(percentage: $percentage)
                .frame(width: maxCanvasVisibilitySize.width)
            
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: percentage) { newValue in
            if (!canvasIsDragging) {
                
                canvasCurrentOffset.width = newValue*((max - min)/2.0)
                canvasLastOffset = canvasCurrentOffset
                
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            
            makeMaxMin()
            
            canvasCurrentOffset.width = -(min + (max - min)/2.0)
            canvasLastOffset = canvasCurrentOffset
            
            percentage = canvasCurrentOffset.width/((max - min)/2.0)
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    private func makeMaxMin() {
        if (circleCurrentOffset.width >= circle2CurrentOffset.width) {
            max = circleCurrentOffset.width + circleSize.width/2.0
        }
        else {
            max = circle2CurrentOffset.width + circle2Size.width/2.0
        }
        
        if (circleCurrentOffset.width <= circle2CurrentOffset.width) {
            min = circleCurrentOffset.width - circleSize.width/2.0
        }
        else {
            min = circle2CurrentOffset.width - circle2Size.width/2.0
        }
    }
    
    private var circleDragGesture: some Gesture {
        
        return DragGesture(minimumDistance: CGFloat.zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged() { gestureValue in
                
                circleIsDragging = true
                
                circleCurrentOffset = CGSize(width: gestureValue.translation.width + circleLastOffset.width, height: .zero)
                
                makeMaxMin()
                
                percentage = canvasCurrentOffset.width/((max - min)/2.0)
                
            }
            .onEnded() { gestureValue in
                circleLastOffset = circleCurrentOffset
                circleIsDragging = false
            }
        
    }
    
    
    
    private var circle2DragGesture: some Gesture {
        
        return DragGesture(minimumDistance: CGFloat.zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged() { gestureValue in
                
                circle2IsDragging = true
                
                circle2CurrentOffset = CGSize(width: gestureValue.translation.width + circle2LastOffset.width, height: .zero)
                
                makeMaxMin()
                
                percentage = canvasCurrentOffset.width/((max - min)/2.0)
                
                
            }
            .onEnded() { gestureValue in
                circle2LastOffset = circle2CurrentOffset
                circle2IsDragging = false
            }
        
    }
    
    private var canvasDragGesture: some Gesture {
        
        return DragGesture(minimumDistance: CGFloat.zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged() { gestureValue in
                
                canvasIsDragging = true
                
                canvasCurrentOffset = CGSize(width: gestureValue.translation.width + canvasLastOffset.width, height: .zero)
                
                makeMaxMin()
                
                percentage = canvasCurrentOffset.width/((max - min)/2.0)
                
                
            }
            .onEnded() { gestureValue in
                canvasLastOffset = canvasCurrentOffset
                canvasIsDragging = false
            }
        
    }
}


struct SliderView: View {
    
    init(percentage: Binding<CGFloat>) {
        self._percentage = percentage
    }
    
    @Binding var percentage: CGFloat
    
    @State private var knobLastOffset: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var knobCurrentOffset: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var knobIsDragging: Bool = Bool()
    
    private let knobSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 30.0)
    
    @State private var sliderGeometrySize: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometryValue in
            
            ZStack {
                
                Color.white
                
                Color.blue.opacity(0.75)
                    .frame(width: knobSize.width)
                    .offset(x: knobCurrentOffset)
                    .gesture(knobDragGesture)
                
            }
            .onAppear { sliderGeometrySize = geometryValue.size }
            .onChange(of: geometryValue.size) { newValue in
                sliderGeometrySize = newValue
                
                let upperRangeOffset = (newValue.width - knobSize.width)/2.0
                let lowerRangeOffset = -upperRangeOffset
                
                knobCurrentOffset = offsetRegulatorWithPercentage(percentage: percentage, upperRangeOffset: upperRangeOffset, lowerRangeOffset: lowerRangeOffset)
                knobLastOffset = knobCurrentOffset
                
            }
            
        }
        .frame(height: knobSize.height)
        .onChange(of: percentage) { newValue in
            if (!knobIsDragging) {
                
                let upperRangeOffset = (sliderGeometrySize.width - knobSize.width)/2.0
                let lowerRangeOffset = -upperRangeOffset
                
                knobCurrentOffset = offsetRegulatorWithPercentage(percentage: newValue, upperRangeOffset: upperRangeOffset, lowerRangeOffset: lowerRangeOffset)
                knobLastOffset = knobCurrentOffset
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private var knobDragGesture: some Gesture {
        
        return DragGesture(minimumDistance: CGFloat.zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged() { gestureValue in
                
                knobIsDragging = true
                let internalOffset = gestureValue.translation.width + knobLastOffset
                let upperRangeOffset = (sliderGeometrySize.width - knobSize.width)/2.0
                let lowerRangeOffset = -upperRangeOffset
                
                knobCurrentOffset = offsetRegulator(internalOffset: internalOffset, upperRangeOffset: upperRangeOffset, lowerRangeOffset: lowerRangeOffset)
                percentage = -1.0 * knobCurrentOffset / ((sliderGeometrySize.width - knobSize.width)/2.0)
                
            }
            .onEnded() { gestureValue in
                knobLastOffset = knobCurrentOffset
                knobIsDragging = false
            }
        
    }
    
    private func offsetRegulator(internalOffset: CGFloat, upperRangeOffset: CGFloat, lowerRangeOffset: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        
        if (internalOffset >= .zero) {
            
            if (internalOffset < upperRangeOffset)  {
                return internalOffset
            }
            else {
                return upperRangeOffset
            }
            
        }
        else {
            
            if (internalOffset > lowerRangeOffset)  {
                return internalOffset
            }
            else {
                return lowerRangeOffset
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private func offsetRegulatorWithPercentage(percentage: CGFloat, upperRangeOffset: CGFloat, lowerRangeOffset: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let internalOffset: CGFloat =  -1.0 * percentage * upperRangeOffset
        return offsetRegulator(internalOffset: internalOffset, upperRangeOffset: upperRangeOffset, lowerRangeOffset: lowerRangeOffset)
        
    }
}


func screenRectangle(string: String, size: CGSize, cornerRadius: CGFloat, color: Color, dash: Bool = false, topOffset: Bool = true) -> some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        .stroke(color, style: dash ? StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4.0, lineCap: .round, dash: [25.0, 25.0]) : StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4.0))
        .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
        .overlay(alignment: .top ) {
            Text("\(string): \(String(format: "%.2f", size.width)) X \(String(format: "%.2f", size.height))").myTextStyle(color: color).offset(y: topOffset ? -30.0 : 15.0)
        }
}

extension View {
    func myTextStyle(color: Color = Color.black) -> some View {
        return self
            .font(Font.system(.body, design: .monospaced).weight(.bold))
            .foregroundColor(color)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .fixedSize()
    }
}


I see you deleted your previous question? I was about to post an answer with code for you. Is this any different from the previous question?

It is different, you can answer that, then answer this.

if I set circleLastOffset width: 100.0 and circle2LastOffset width: -50.0 then max - min is 200. for this scenario 2 questions, why not 150 for max - min? and on appear why canvasCurrentOffset (-25.0, 0.0)?

Why did you create a custom SliderView rather than using the built-in SwiftUI Slider View? The built-in Slider has settable maximum and minimum values.

@Immanuel: If we can find the answer in general terms, we can then discuss the exceptions as well.

@DuncanC: The custom slider adjusts the values between -1.0 and 1.0, which is its only purpose. Additionally, I really like the custom UI.

@swiftPunk, if circles are 100 and 50, what is the expected green square width, 150 or 200, and what is the center, is it 0 or equal on both sides?

@Immanuel: No need to make it complicated. The situation in the question is where the issue appears. You can use the question data as it is.

@swiftPunk, I have an answer for circle width equal values and dragging slider, it is just a simple calculation change in .onChange(of: percentage). But the scenarios of circles with different initial width, dragging canvas and changing circles position breaks the solution

@Immanuel: I made this unnecessary update just because you asked. As I said, I am not going to say anything that wasn’t in the question. In the question, the circle sizes were fixed and the same. I could accept answers that solve the issue under the given conditions.

sorry @swiftPunk, I was mentioning about the circle offsets width, not the circle.
this worked if offsets are same width and only when using slider. broken for other cases.
.onChange(of: percentage) { newValue in
if (!canvasIsDragging) {
            canvasCurrentOffset.width = ((maxCanvasVisibilitySize.width - (max - min)) / 2) * newValue
            canvasLastOffset = canvasCurrentOffset
            
        }
    }


@Immanuel: I know that, but that is part of the correct answer. I intentionally chose different sizes to solve the issue. If the offsets were the same, as you mentioned, we would need maxCanvasVisibilitySize.width. However, in my question, the offsets are different. Besides that, I added a drag gesture to the circles to update the offsets while the app is running.

@swiftPunk I posted an answer to show a simpler way to go about it. To be frank, I don't really get the need for the multiple circle drag gestures and all that complexity. The circles don't need to follow an offset if you simply align them to the left and to the right of the panning frame.

@swiftpunk Have you had a chance to look at the answer I provided?

@AndreiG.: Yes, unfortunately I did not satisfied with your answer, but thanks for your help.

@swiftPunk no problem, but it would be useful to know what aspect of the answer wasn’t suitable, for future reference.

@AndreiG.: To be honest, you ignored all the app logic, names, and used a specific situation to obtain an answer. You introduced a different UI, for example, by using Apple’s Slider, ... .You simply destroyed my question.
If I were to answer someone’s question, I would try to understand the logic behind it, look at the code and the issue as if I were the original poster (OP), and then try to fix the code or the issue—rather than completely changing the question into something else.
I’m just letting you know this because you asked for the reason.

I see. Well, I thought I did exactly that - I looked at the code, tried to understand the logic, disagreed with the logic, offered one that was more streamlined and took the time to explain it. I thought that by offering you a simpler way to approach the problem, it was a way to fix the issue you were having and quite possibly subsequent ones. I appreciate you telling me all this, I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Note: I put this code together before you made edits to the question and possibly code, which I am not sure what they consist of.
To answer your question:

How can I match the fixed range of a slider to a dynamic range in
SwiftUI?

Answer: To match the fixed range of the slider to some other range is called normalizing values.
To do this, you need to know the panning offset limits and then normalize them relative to your slider range, such that the maximum offset in any direction is proportional to either 1 or -1.
For example, if your maximum offset when panning right is 500, it's as if the slider value was 1. This means that an offset of 325 would translate to:
sliderPosition = offset / (maxOffset * maxSliderPosition)
sliderPosition = 325 / (500 * 1) 
sliderPosition = 0.65

This is easier to see if you consider a more obvious position like half the distance. So consider it the other way around: if your slider is halfway to the right (having a 0.5 value), the corresponding offset will be:
offset = maxOffset * sliderPosition
offset = 500 * 0.5
offset = 250

If you plug this back in the previous formula: sliderPosition = 250 / (500 * 1) = 0.5.
So the key here is to find the maximum range the frame can be panned and this is simple. If the canvas width is 400 and the frame width is say 700, the frame is 700 - 400 = 300 bigger than the canvas, meaning that when starting from either end, if the total panning is more than 300, you're out of bounds.
If you consider a centered starting position (since your slider starts centered at 0), then the max panning distance going either direction (right or left) can be no more than half the total range: 300 / 2 = 150.
This would mean that dragging left a distance of -150 (from the center) is as if the slider reached its left limit of -1, and dragging right a distance of 150 would represent a slider at its right limit of 1.
For example, if dragging left a distance of 100, would correspond to a slider position of:
sliderPosition = -100 / (150 * 1) = -0.67

With this approach, you don't even need a GeometryReader because it uses relative values based on widths and and gesture distance.
Here's the working code example which uses a more simplified code structure, including a regular Slider and some buttons to control the canvas size to show it's all dynamic:
import SwiftUI

struct FramePanner: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var canvasSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 250)
    @State private var position: Double = 0 // This will represent normalized position from -1 to 1
    @State private var panningFramePosition: Double = 0 // Tracks frame position at the start of drag

    //Constants
    private let panningFrameSize: CGFloat = 700
    private let normalizedRange: ClosedRange<Double> = -1...1 // The min and max range of the slider
    
    //Computed properties
    
    //The difference between the panning frame size and the canvas size is the total distance that can be panned
    private var panningTotalRange: CGFloat {
        return panningFrameSize - canvasSize.width
    }
    
    //The maximum distance the view can be panned left or right based on a centered starting position (half of the total available range)
    private var lateralRange: CGFloat {
        return panningTotalRange / 2
    }
    
    //Calculate the actual position based on the normalized position (which ranges from -1 to 1).
    private var panningOffset: CGFloat {
        return position * lateralRange
    }
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        //Drag gesture
        let canvasDragGesture = DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                
                //Determine drag relative to total possible distance in either direction
                let relativeDrag = value.translation.width / lateralRange
                
                //Update position based on relative drag, such that it's within the normalized range bounds (-1 to 1)
                position = (panningFramePosition + relativeDrag).clamped(to: normalizedRange)
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                // Update frame position after drag ends
                panningFramePosition = position
            }
        
        //Wrapper
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            VStack {
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Color.black
                        .gesture(canvasDragGesture)
                    
                    Color.clear
                        .background {
                            Rectangle()
                                .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 3)
                                .frame(width: panningFrameSize)
                            //Left purple circle
                                .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(Color.purple)
                                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                }
                            //Right yellow circle
                                .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(Color.yellow)
                                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                }
                                .offset(x: panningOffset)
                                .gesture(canvasDragGesture)
                        }
                    
                    //Values labels
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Canvas width: \(String(format: "%.0f", canvasSize.width))")
                        Text("Position: \(String(format: "%.1f", position)) | \(String(format: "%.1f%%", position * 100))")
                        Text("Offset: \(String(format: "%.1f", panningOffset))")
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding()
                }
                .frame(width: canvasSize.width, height: canvasSize.height)
                
                //Slider view
                Slider(value: $position, in: normalizedRange)
                    .tint(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.clear)
                    .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
                        withAnimation {
                            position = 0 //Reset position on double tap of slider track
                        }
                    })
                
                //Slider caption
                Text("Double tap slider track to reset position")
                    .font(.caption2)
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
            }
            .frame(width: canvasSize.width) //Constrain the slider to the canvas width
            
            //Buttons for controlling canvas size
            HStack {
                Text("Canvas size:")
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                
                //Decrease canvas width
                Button("-") {
                    withAnimation(.smooth){
                        canvasSize.width *= 0.9
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .disabled(canvasSize.width <= 300)
                
                //Increase canvas width
                Button("+") {
                    withAnimation(.smooth){
                        canvasSize.width *= 1.1
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .disabled(canvasSize.width >= 550)

                //Reset canvas width
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.smooth){
                        canvasSize.width = 400
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "gobackward")
                        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                        .imageScale(.small)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

extension Comparable {
    //Helper function to restrict a value within a specified range, ensuring that the value doesn’t exceed the defined minimum or maximum limits
    func clamped(to range: ClosedRange<Self>) -> Self {
        min(max(self, range.lowerBound), range.upperBound)
    }
}

//Preview
#Preview {
    FramePanner()
}


NOTE: Assumes a landscape iPhone orientation in Xcode Preview
